# accessing variables from view controller to the override function

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, mobile

I am making an app that selects a random  question from my array every time I shake my phone. As shown below; I tried to call the "print" function in the "override function motionBegan" but it didn't work. Can anyone help.?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let array  = ["what did your eat for breakfast?", "First time you kissed a boy/girl? Explain.", "Whats your body count?", "When was the last time you went to church?", "Would you date someone from another religion?", "East booty(Guy) ?or let a guy eat your booty(Girl)?", "If you die right now where will you end?", "whats on your mind?", "Ever has a one night stand?", "Do you find the other person attractive?", "How old where you when you first hd sex?. Explain.", "You believe in Jesus?", "Where do you see yourself in 10 years?", "First time you gave head?", "Slap your mum or your dad? Choose one.", "Last time you watched porn?", "How much is in your account?", "One thing you hate about the other person?", "One thing you love about the other person?", "Would you kiss the person close to you?", "One thing you hate about yourself?", " One thing you love about yourself?","Suck toes or eat booty?", "Best rapper?", "Best singer?", "If you had a billion dollars for 24 hours how will you spend it?"]

            let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))
            // Get a random item
            let  randomItem = array[randomIndex]

        func print() {
            textField.text = randomItem
        }
    }

    override func motionBegan(_ motion: UIEventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print;

    }
```

Comment: What's the issue? are you having to `override` when implementing `motionBegan` function?

Comment: you are selecting dynamic question in Didload instead make it to select in a function created and call the new created function at end of detected motion and once in didLoad hope it helps

Comment: Are you sure your code is well formated, don't you have too much closed bracket before your method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to start printing the random values. You need to get the random value when the motion begins. Also you need to bring the print function out of the viewDidLoad so it can be called everytime.

```
let array  = ["what did your eat for breakfast?", "First time you kissed a boy/girl? Explain.", "Whats your body count?", "When was the last time you went to church?", "Would you date someone from another religion?", "East booty(Guy) ?or let a guy eat your booty(Girl)?", "If you die right now where will you end?", "whats on your mind?", "Ever has a one night stand?", "Do you find the other person attractive?", "How old where you when you first hd sex?. Explain.", "You believe in Jesus?", "Where do you see yourself in 10 years?", "First time you gave head?", "Slap your mum or your dad? Choose one.", "Last time you watched porn?", "How much is in your account?", "One thing you hate about the other person?", "One thing you love about the other person?", "Would you kiss the person close to you?", "One thing you hate about yourself?", " One thing you love about yourself?","Suck toes or eat booty?", "Best rapper?", "Best singer?", "If you had a billion dollars for 24 hours how will you spend it?"]
var randomItem = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func printing() {
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))
    randomItem = array[randomIndex]         
    textField.text = randomItem
}

override func motionBegan(_ motion: UIEventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.printing() 
}
```

Comment: This Worked!!!! Thanks man!

Comment: Do you have an idea on how to prevent the app from asking the same questions until I have asked all the questions in the array? You think I can delete the question item from the array every time i ask it until the array == 0?

Comment: hi thanks, yes sure. what you need to do is create another array which is filled by taking the elements randomly from the list and also deleting those elements from the other list. once you have this array, you can start it from the start and you don't need to take the objects from it randomly.